# Android: keep Fragment running

Tags: android, android-fragments

Is it possible to keep a Fragment running while I call `replace` from `FragmentManager` to open a new Fragment?

Basically I don't want to pause a Fragment when navigating (via `replace` method) to another Fragment.

Is it possible?
Or the correct approach is, always, instantiate a new Fragment every time I need to open it and restore its previous state?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you replacing the old fragment with new fragment?

Comment: Try hiding the fragment instead of replacing or removing.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Yes, I'm replacing.

Comment: @Ercan Will try, thanks, but if I hide I'll have to open the other fragment in another layout I suppose, otherwise it will overwrite the current one, no?

Comment: It stay there if you won't use replace or remove methods.You can even load other fragments without removing the previous one in the same layout. Last one that you load will be on top and visible(If the one on top is transparent it will be visible ofc)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

FragmentManger replace method will destroy the previous fragment completely, So in each transaction onDestroyView(), onDestroy() and onDetach() will get called on previous fragment. If you want to keep your fragment running you can instead use FragmentManger hide() and show() methods! It hides and shows the fragments without destroying them.

so first add both fragments to fragment manager and also hide the second fragment.

```
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.new_card_container, FragmentA)
            .add(R.id.new_card_container,FragmentB)
            .hide(FragmentB)
            .commit();
```

Note that you can only call show() on hidden fragment. So here you can't call show() on FragmentA but it's not a problem because by hiding and showing FragmentB you can get replacement effect you want.

And here is a method to go back and forth between your fragments.

```
public void showOtherFragment() {

    if(FragmentB.isHidden()){
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .show(FragmentB).commit();

    } else {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .hide(FragmentB).commit();
    }
}
```

Now if you put log message in fragment callback method you will see there is no destruction (except for screen orientation change!), even view will not get destroyed since onDistroyView doesn't get called.

There is only one problem and that is, first time when application starts onCreateView() method get called one time for each fragment (and it should be!) but when the orientation changes onCreateView() gets called twice for each fragment and that's because fragments once created as usual and once because of there attachment to FragmentManger (saved on bundle object) To avoid that you have two options 1) detach fragments in onSaveInstaneState() callback.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .detach(FragmentA)
            .detach(FragmentB)
            .commit();

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

It's working but view state will not get updated automatically, for example if you have a EditText its text will erase each time orientation change happens. of course you can fix this simply by saving states in the fragment but you don't have to if you use the second option!

first i save a Boolean value in onSaveInstaneState() method to remember witch fragment is shown.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    boolean isFragAVisible = true;
    if(!FragmentB.isHidden())
        isFragAVisible = false;

    outState.putBoolean("isFragAVisible",isFragAVisible);

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

now in activity onCreate method i check to see if savedInstanceState == null. if yes do as usual if not activity is created for second time. so fragment manager already contains the fragments. So instead i'm getting a reference to my fragments from fragment manager. also i make sure correct fragment is shown since its not recovered automatically.

```
    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    if(savedInstanceState == null){

        FragmentA = new FragmentA();
        FragmentB = new FragmentB();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.new_card_container, FragmentA, "fragA")
                .add(R.id.new_card_container, FragmentB, "fragB")
                .hide(FragmentB)
                .commit();

    } else {
        FragmentA = (FragmentA) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("fragA");
        FragmentB = (FragmentB) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("fragB");

        boolean isFragAVisible = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isFragAVisible");
        if(isFragAVisible)
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .hide(FragmentB)
                    .commit();
        else
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .hide(FragmetA) //only if using transaction animation
                    .commit();
    }
```

By now your fragment will work perfectly if are not using transaction animation. If you do, you also need to show and hide FragmentA. So when you want to show FragmentB first hide FragmentA then show FragmentB (in the same transaction) and when you want to hide FragmentB hide it first and also show FragmentA (again in the same transaction). Here is my code for card flip animation (downloaded from developer.goodle.com)

```
public void flipCard(String direction) {
    int animationEnter, animationLeave;
    if(direction == "left"){
        animationEnter = R.animator.card_flip_right_in;
        animationLeave = R.animator.card_flip_right_out;
    } else {
        animationEnter = R.animator.card_flip_left_in;
        animationLeave = R.animator.card_flip_left_out;
    }

    if(cardBack.isHidden()){
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(animationEnter, animationLeave)
                .hide(cardFront)
                .show(cardBack)
                .commit();

    } else {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(animationEnter,animationLeave)
                .hide(cardBack)
                .show(cardFront)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, when I replace with an existing Fragment instance, it doesn't call the onCreateView (which seems correct according to the docs). Then... my controls are not visible since it doesn't go through the layout inflate. Should I inflate in the onResume? It sounds a bit weird to me to inflate and populate the controls every time it resumes. Also, the onResume doesn't have the Bundle for saved info. Any help?

Comment: I just tested what you said by putting a Toast inside fragment onCreateView() and the result was it gets called for every transaction not only the first time, and it should be because when fragment disappears from screen onDistroyView() get called so when it comes back there is no view and it should be created. Any way i don't think your problem comes from fragment transaction. Post your fragment code here, it may help us to see what the problem is.

Comment: I found out something amazing about FragmentManager today and it really helped me in the app i'm currently developing. I think you would be happy too! see the edited answer