# Running a fragment in the background if not visible

Tags: android, android-fragments

so i have an android application that has 3 fragments on the main activity. A fragment with a countdown timer, a fragment for Settings, and a third fragment. I am trying to start my timer, and navigate through the application such as open the other fragments while continuing the timer to countdown. But unfortunately once i start the timer and navigate to another fragment the timer stops. When i return to the timer fragment it sets the timer back to the original state as if it never was started. I have tried Fragment.setRetainInstance(boolean), with no luck. Any idea as to how i should allow the fragment to continue running in the background as a open different fragments up?

```
public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Class fragmentClass;
        switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_first_fragment:
                fragmentClass = HomeFragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_second_fragment:
                fragmentClass = StatsFragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_third_fragment:
                fragmentClass = SettingsFragment.class;
                break;
            default:
                fragmentClass = HomeFragment.class;
        }

        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();





        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
        mDrawer.closeDrawers();
    }
```

Comment: Where are you starting your timer? Please start it inside the Container Activity onResume using a Handler. and never forget to stop it at OnStop of Activity.

Comment: So you are saying to have the timer running in the container activity as opposed to inside of the actual fragment? Run on the container activity and solely display it on the fragment

Comment: Yes I am saying so..try and let me know

Answer (score 0):

check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36478403/2071936) try to add fragment instead of replace.

**UPDATE**

try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25151895/2071936) it has a more details .. i think it can help

Comment: The fragment visually overlaps the previous fragment. So it just a bunch of images and text sitting ontop of each other. And the timer is still resetting.

Comment: could you put your code that used for inflate fragment

Comment: i have updated my answer check it ..  would it help you

Comment: i have also posted my code above. i will take a look at your updated answer now. thanks!